# Message: HTTP Error: (0) Failed to connect to accounts.google.com port 80: Connection timed out

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, port, google-signin

I am trying to login using google with codeigniter framework.
It was working fine before. same code gives below error message now.
How can I solve this ?

Localhost shows below error

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: apiIOException

Message: HTTP Error: (0) Unsupported proxy scheme for 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'

Filename: application\third_party\google-login-api\io\apiCurlIO.php
```

after hosted at server it shows below error

```
Type: apiIOException

Message: HTTP Error: (0) Failed to connect to accounts.google.com port 80: Connection timed out

Filename: application/third_party/google-login-api/io/apiCurlIO.php
```

**below is my curl script**

```
 $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $request->getUrl()); //your proxy url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "80"); // your proxy port number
    curl_setopt_array($ch, self::$DEFAULT_CURL_PARAMS);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request->getUrl());
    if ($request->getPostBody()) {
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request->getPostBody());
    }

    $requestHeaders = $request->getRequestHeaders();
    if ($requestHeaders && is_array($requestHeaders)) {
      $parsed = array();
      foreach ($requestHeaders as $k => $v) {
        $parsed[] = "$k: $v";
      }
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $parsed);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $request->getRequestMethod());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $request->getUserAgent());

    $respData = curl_exec($ch);

    // Retry if certificates are missing.
    if (curl_errno($ch) == CURLE_SSL_CACERT) {
      error_log('SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK.'
        . ' Retrying with the CA cert bundle from google-api-php-client.');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacerts.pem');
      $respData = curl_exec($ch);
    }

    $respHeaderSize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $respHttpCode = (int) curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $curlErrorNum = curl_errno($ch);
    $curlError = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($curlErrorNum != CURLE_OK) {
      throw new apiIOException("HTTP Error: ($respHttpCode) $curlError");
    }
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: @DanielStenberg can you please see the updated question ? when i  have uploaded files to the server ,error message changed

Comment: "Failed to connect to accounts.google.com port 80". Means exactly what it says. curl failed to connect to TCP port 80 on the host "accounts.google.com" from that machine. Due to network setup, a firewall or something.

Comment: @DanielStenberg then how can i check that is there any firewall on server or not ? or what is blocking my request ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a code for login with gmail in codeigntor. You can change code and try with following 4 File. I am sure this code help to you.

File1 : 
config/googleplus.php :

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config['googleplus']['application_name'] = 'abc';
$config['googleplus']['client_id']        = '#######';
$config['googleplus']['client_secret']    = '#######';
$config['googleplus']['redirect_uri']     = 'abc.com/social_login';

$config['googleplus']['api_key']          = '######';
$config['googleplus']['scopes']           = array();
?>
```

File2 : 
libraries/Googleplus.php :

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
  class Googleplus {

   public function __construct() {

    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->config->load('googleplus');

    require APPPATH .'third_party/google-login-api/apiClient.php';
    require APPPATH .'third_party/google-login-api/contrib/apiOauth2Service.php';



    $this->client = new apiClient();
    $this->client->setApplicationName($CI->config->item('application_name', 'googleplus'));
    $this->client->setClientId($CI->config->item('client_id', 'googleplus'));
    $this->client->setClientSecret($CI->config->item('client_secret', 'googleplus'));
    $this->client->setRedirectUri($CI->config->item('redirect_uri', 'googleplus'));
    $this->client->setDeveloperKey($CI->config->item('api_key', 'googleplus'));
    $this->client->setScopes($CI->config->item('scopes', 'googleplus'));
    $this->client->setAccessType('online');
    $this->client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');
    $this->oauth2 = new apiOauth2Service($this->client);

}

public function loginURL() {
    return $this->client->createAuthUrl();
}

public function getAuthenticate() {
    return $this->client->authenticate();
}

public function getAccessToken() {
    return $this->client->getAccessToken();
}

public function setAccessToken() {
    return $this->client->setAccessToken();
}

public function revokeToken() {
    return $this->client->revokeToken();
}

public function getUserInfo() {
    return $this->oauth2->userinfo->get();
}

}
?>
```

File3 : 
controller/login.php :

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Login extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('Googleplus');
}

    $data['login_url'] = $this->googleplus->loginURL();
    $this->load->view('user_login', $data);
}
?>
```

File4 : 
views/login.php :

```
<a href="<?php echo $login_url;?>">Login with google</a>
```